# How can I not be able to construct dependencies before passing them in?

Tags: android, dependency-injection

When reading [this cool manual about DI](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection) I don't understand this part:

> When you're not able to construct dependencies before passing them in — for example when using lazy initializations or scoping objects to flows of your app — you need to write and maintain a custom container (or graph of dependencies) that manages the lifetimes of your dependencies in memory.

How can I not be able to construct dependencies before passing them in? Can you give a real example, preferably from Android world? I know there is explanation in that paragraph I quoted but it does not help me to understand.

Comment: Context is king. That is a bullet point under Manual dependency injection (Pure DI). They are referring to the dependency not being available for injection at the time of activating the subject class.

Comment: activating? there's no such thing, you mean contructing or injecting or passing dependencies into?

Comment: activating the class is the same as initializing it with all its dependencies.